# Function takes a dictionary with list as value, returns the key of the biggest list

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map

I created a function that takes a dictionary as parameter. This dictionary is expected to have lists as value pair. *(i.e. `{1: [1, 2, 3], 'a': [4, 'b', 5, 'c']}` )*

This function has to return the key associated to the biggest list in the dictionary, or `None` if the dictionary is empty. *(considering the above example, it would return `'a'` )*

I came up with this code:

```py
def biggest(aDict):
    return None if not aDict else [x for x in aDict if len(aDict[x]) == max(len(x) for x in aDict.values())][0]
```

Can I have some review on this and any ideas on how to further simplify without using external libraries?

Comment: 1 LOC doesn't equate to good code. At the very least this shouldn't use a turnery or nested comprehensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is difficult to read:

- The line is too long (according to the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) all lines should be limited to 79 characters).
- The same iterator variable `x` is used for the outer iteration and also inside the `max()` function.

It is also inefficient because the maximal list length is determined in each iteration.

Using the `key` and `default` argument of the [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function the same can be concisely and efficiently be implemented as

```
def biggest(aDict):
    return max(aDict, key=lambda k: len(aDict[k]), default=None)
```

More suggestions:

- Have a look at the [Python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) (`snake_case`, not `camelCase`).
- Choose a more descriptive function name.
- Use [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to describe the function.

Comment: This is the kind of answer that I was needing! I have just started to learn python. I come from Java, so camelCase is the way to go, for me. Hehe. Also, I realize the line was big enough,but I just wanted to exploit python capabilities of one-lining all the logic, to get a better understanding of the language.

Comment: Also, would you care to explain, what the param key exactly does? Does it only accept a lambda?

Comment: @msmilkshake: It can be any function taking a single argument: a “named” function or an “anonymous” function (lambda). See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort: “key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element”